# How to fix the out of memory issue?

Tags: matlab, memory, memory-management, matlab-guide

I have a matrix `A`, the size of which is 2000*50000 double. I want to calculate the 
covariance matrix of matrix `A`, so I use this Matlab Command:

```
Y = cov(A)
```

But there is error popping up:

```
Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your
options.
Error in test_2 (line 31)
Y = cov(A)
```

My D disk still has 250 GB. Why it come up this error?
How to fix this problem?

Comment: MEMORY refers here to the RAM of your computer, not your ROM. Is A sparse, i.e. an array for which most of the values are zeros ?

Comment: @Ratbert, no, A is not sparse. I want to get the covariance matrix of A. How to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need at least 0.8(GB) to store `A` in memory. If you look in `cov.m`, you'll see that matlab is computing the covariance matrix with (I'm using your variable names below)

```
Y = (A' * A) / size(A,1);
```

Since `A` is 2k x 50k, `A' * A` will be 50k x 50k, which takes 20(GB) of memory. I am guessing that your machine does not have that much available. You can still compute the covariance matrix, but you'll have to write your own function to calculate it in blocks/pieces and also store the result to file rather than keeping it memory.

Comment: store the result to file, do you mean save it as .mat file?

Comment: What I mean by save it to file is to calculate `Y(1,1)` and then write that value to file. Then calculate `Y(2,1)` and write it to file, and so on and so on. As for how to write the function, a simple internet search will show you how to calculate each entry. It's then up to you to figure out how many you can do at one time.

Comment: Not to sound like a jerk, but no. Some amount of effort is expected on your part and I am not going to google things for you.